# React create element with key

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm attempting to render an array of react components without JSX with keys. The problem Unfortunately, I'm dealing with a JS error when i attempt to set the keys inside of my array:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'key' of object '#<Object>'
```

Here is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Test extends Component {

  mapChildObjects = () => {
    const { children } = this.props;
    let arr = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
      arr.push(React.createElement(children[i]));
      arr[i].key = i;
    }
    return arr;
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <div className={s.content}>
          {this.mapChildObjects()}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default Test
```

After reading the documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html, but was unable to find examples of adding keys inside of `createElement`.

Note: this renders fine; the issue is not with the rendering of the component, but with the ability to add keys creating elements.

Comment: IIRC `key` is a property, so I think something like `React.createElement(children[i], {key: i})` might work.

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you zzzzBov

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As zzzzBov mentioned in the comments, `key` is a prop and can be passed inside an object as the second parameter of [createElement](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement).

Example

```js
mapChildObjects = () => {
    const { children } = this.props;

    return children.map((child, i) => {
       return React.createElement(child, {key: i});
    });
  }
```

Comment:  for the writeup.

Comment: Works as a charm

Answer (score 0):

```js
  const tag = "div";
  const key = "myDiv";
  const className ="your class Name";
  const your childrenOrText = "thisCaseisTextOnly";

  const theTag = createElement(tag, { key: key, className }, childrenOrText );
```